# Interface index specification while creating a socket in Python

Tags: python, sockets

How do I specify the interface index when creating a socket in Python 2.6.6?
More specifically, does anyone know of SO_BINDTODEVICE functionality in Python? In C, it looks like this:
http://codingrelic.geekhold.com/2009/10/code-snippet-sobindtodevice.html

Comment: Please be more specific

Comment: Most probably you want to create a socket and then call "bind" on it with IP address of the interface you're interested in (which you have to figure out separately).